# Windows xp - remove startmenu rightclick entries "open all users" / "explore all users"

Tags: windows-xp, windows-registry

How can I remove the "Open All Users" / "Explore All Users" entries when right-clicking the windows startbutton?

I know I managed to do this when deploying another batch of systems earlier, sadly I can't find the appropriate note how I did it. Must have been a registry entry I think though.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NoCommonGroups` Policy removes the `Open All Users` and `Explore All Users` from the Start context-menu. Take a look at the following link because there a lots of other settings you could use to lock down a system.

[Policy settings for the Start menu in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/default...;EN-US;q292504)

```
Policy:Remove common program groups from Start Menu
Description:Removes items in the All Users profile from the More 
Programs list on the Start menu.
Registry Value:"NoCommonGroups"
```

This `NoCommonGroups.reg` should do the trick for what you asked:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"NoCommonGroups"=dword:00000001
```

Of course you could also go through the `GPEDIT.MSC` options mentioned in the link.

Do not forget to lockdown the system further because otherwise users can change these settings back via the registry for example (or other means if they have the `Run`-menu).

In the following registry script you can find lots of things to lockdown a system: [LockDown.reg](http://users.javanet.com/i/-/i-am-your-g0d/LockDown.reg)
Take a look at it and see what else you can use.

Comment: Thanks, this does exactly what I wanted. Also note, that this hides all `All Users` items in the programs menu as well as on the desktop. (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938264.aspx) Thanks alot for the LockDown.reg link! Looks like there were quite some interesting registry settings in it which I didn't know about yet.